# Difference between while(in) and while(!in.eof())?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have this readFile function.

```
void readFile(People peps[], int& cnt)
{
    ifstream in("people.txt");
    if (!in)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file\n";
    }
    else {
        while (in) //1
        while (!in.eof())//2
        {
            getline(in, peps[cnt].fullname, '-');
            getline(in, peps[cnt].h, '-');
            getline(in, peps[cnt].w, '\n');
            ++cnt;
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

What is the difference between while(in) and while(!in.eof())? Before, I used while(!in.eof()) to detect the end of a file but then I saw my instructor use while (in) instead. I thought they were the same but it seems while(in) reads one more line even at the end of the file?

My people.txt file has 97 lines so `cnt` should be 97 after the while loop finishes executing. For some reason, when I use while(in), `cnt` ends up with 98, and `peps[97]` stores empty strings.

Comment: `!in` detects error conditions other than end of file.  Either way, a `while (in)` or `while (!in.eof())` is not a good idea (effectively your code is assuming all the calls of `getline()` succeed, even if one or more of them fails, which means the count will be a bit whacky).

Comment: Don't use either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: `eof()` checks if the stream has *already* hit the end of the file.  That is, it will only be set *after* an unsuccessful read.  Related (but for C): [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/)

Answer (score 0):

The `while(in)` condition includes *all* the reasons that make the file unreadable, not just eof.

I'm perplexed why that would result in an extra line.  Maybe the last line of your file doesn't end with a newline character?

Comment: Yes. The last line of my file is `Le Pham Ha Giang-162-49` so it does not contain a newline character.

Does that mean I will have to have use while(!in.eof()) instead and cant customize the while(in)?

Comment: @Starlight - That means your code will behave differently depending on whether the last line has a newline at the end or not.   Usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

special function-> eof(), that returns nonzero (meaning TRUE) when there are no more data to be read from an input file stream, and zero (meaning FALSE) otherwise.

Comment: Not quite true.  `eof()` returns true *after* you've tried to read past the end of the file.  The distinction is subtle but critical.